# How to fire event handler only for the specific control in foreach loop

Tags: asp.net, checkbox, foreach

Hello there I have setup some checkboxes inside a foreach loop and adding them to the page controls! I have also assigned them a single eventhandler and passing them my own parameter.

When the checkedchanged event of checkboxes fires it calls that event handler for all the checkboxes I added This is may be because im assigning the eventhandler inside for each loop so whenever the event fires It fires for all of the check boxes! I want it to only been fired once i.e only for the checkbox whose check was changed.

Please help me on it How can I solve the issue
The code snippets may help you understanding the

```
CheckBox checkboxtemp;

foreach (SPListItem item in list.Items)
        {
            checkboxtemp = new CheckBox();
            checkboxtemp.ID = "CheckBoxId" + item.ID;
            checkboxtemp.Text = item.Title;
            checkboxtemp.AutoPostBack = true;
            checkboxtemp.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler((sender, e) => checkboxtemp_CheckedChanged(sender, e, checkboxtemp.Text));
            Controls.Add(checkboxtemp);
        }
```

and the event handler which gets fired for every checkbox is as

```
protected void checkboxtemp_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e, string fieldName)
    {
      Label1.Text = fieldName;
    }
```

No matter which checkbox was checked. I always get the last checkbox text value inside fieldName parameter in checkboxtemp_CheckChanged event handler. i.e when ever any checkbox state gets changed the event handler in the foreach loop gets called for each items..
I know im doing something wrong but cant figure it out

Please help

Comment: is item.ID unique over the items?

Comment: yes the item.ID is unique for each item

Answer (score 0):

Try this

delete

<del>CheckBox checkboxtemp;</del>

```
foreach (SPListItem item in list.Items)
        {

            var checkboxtemp = new CheckBox();
```